# How to use an Eclipselink Converter to serialize a list of objects to json

Tags: eclipselink, converters

I've written a implementation of Converter that uses Jackson JSON to serialize a list of deeply structured objects to JSON, but it's not being called. Am I doing this correctly?

```
 @Converter(name="arrayList", converterClass=ArrayListJsonSerializedObjectConverter.class)
 private List<DeeplyStructuredObject> deeplyStructuredObjects= new ArrayList<DeeplyStructuredObject>();
```

Additionally, I'd like to know whether or not one can use a ReadTransfomer in addition to a 
Converter on the same property, e.g.

```
 @Converter(name="arrayList", converterClass=ArrayListJsonSerializedObjectConverter.class)
 @ReadTransformer(method="someMethod")
 private List<DeeplyStructuredObject> deeplyStructuredObjects= new ArrayList<DeeplyStructuredObject>();
```